Synonym for "of my production"
Let's say I produce something and sell it, e.g. honey. What would I write on the sign outside my shop? My initial ideas don't sound right:

Honey of my production?
In-house honey?

I'm looking for a phrase or idiom that means "of my production". It would appear on a shop sign in the form "_____ honey" or "honey _____".

Home-made honey.

Thanks for your help! Can I use "home-made" although I am a licensed producer that produces and sells my own honey? The meaning I want to convey is that I produce it and I don't buy it from another shop and then resell it.

I think my sounds a bit out of place for a shop - it's more suggestive of a market barrow. If you don't like home-made honey you might consider a sign saying We make and sell our own honey. But I must say the UK regulations look pretty daunting to me. Until I just looked at that page,I had no idea that honey is 'Unsuitable for children
under 12 months' (precautionary measure against possible infant botulism, which could potentially
arise from the presence of Clostridium botulinum spores in honey).

Someone has voted to close, but I think this question is suitable, on-topic and meets the requirements for the tag(s) so I'm voting to keep it open. @EdwinAshworth has offered one solution, but only as a comment. A formal answer would also address the OP's concern about whether the proposed idiom or phrase conveys a suitably respectable message for a shop as compared to (say) a market barrow. :)

While today you can say "We produce all our own honey," tomorrow you may find other sources of wonderful honey and want to feature them, too. Then what will you do? In the American South, you can produce orange blossom honey and tupelo honey, but you how will you produce them elsewhere? They have flavors that are unique and outstanding.

I wouldn't call honey home-made - the bees make it! You could say Honey from our own bees/hives.

In New York City several years ago I noticed that restaurants were sometimes advertising "house made" rather than "home made" items that would typically be bought from a manufacturer (for example, ketchup).  At first I thought it pretentious, but then I figured that they're trying to be more truthful: nobody calls a restaurant a "home," but it is a "house" (in one sense of house although not the primary sense).  I am sympathetic to @KateBunting's comment, though, nobody makes honey unless they're a bee.  Another word to consider is apiary.

Using @KateBunting proposal, I suggest "Honey straight from our hives".

Local honey harvester; people are not bees. People want to know it's local for allergen reasons.

Sign: We love our honey bees.

There are many ways as suggested in the comments. I thought of "Home-produced honey" and searching Google images with that phrase yields

Home-produced honey
Home-grown honey (not sure about that: honey isn't grown)
{Name of farm} honey (which immediately identifies it as yours even outside your own immediate area)
Locally-made honey (which doesn't necessarily mean it's yours)

as well as the more poetic "Honey from our hives/bees" and the like.
A short pithy synonym for "of my production" would be "home-produced".
